# Error in React Native with Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

**Error I am getting:**

Nothing is displaying in the App screen but when I console log it's fetching data from the server in the terminal.

**app screen feedscreen.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Text, View, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import stylesheet from '../src/styles/HomeStyle';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const FeedScreen = props => {

  const [text, setText] = useState('loading');
  const Boiler = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    fetch('http://192.168.*.*:3000/post', {
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setText(data.text);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    Boiler();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={stylesheet.container}>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FeedScreen;
```

**My MongoDB table:**

[image]

**Console log:**

```
LOG  Running "AwesomeProject" with {"rootTag":61,"initialProps":{}}
 LOG  {"email": "test@demo.com", "name": "test demo"}
 LOG  [{"_id": "5e436d9112911336750a9fa6", "slug": "this-is-node-express-and-mongodb", "text": "This is  node express and mongodb.", "user": [[Object]]}, {"_id": "5e3a976d5ca38b812a93d5fa", "slug": "this-is-the-social-network-api-which-is-build-on-top-of-node-express-and-mongodb", "text": "This is the social network api which is build on top of node express and mongodb.", "user": [[Object]]}, {"_id": "5e3a975d5ca38b812a93d5f9", "slug": "this-is-the-social-network-api-which-is-build-on-top-of-node-express-and-mongodb", "text": "This is the social network api which is build on top of node express and mongodb.", "user": [[Object]]}]
```

Comment: It seems your `data` is an array, try to call `setText(data[0].text);`

Comment: but this can only return one data only

Comment: Yes, if you want show all data, you can use FlatList